# Root of Unity Proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, roots-of-unity

Here is my question:

> Let $\zeta$ be the first $n$-th root of unity, and let $\eta$ = $\zeta^k$ be any other $n$-th root of unity. Show that there exists an integer $m$ such that $\zeta = \eta^m$ *if and only if* $k$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Today was my first lecture in working with modular addition, subtraction, and multiplication. I know how to compute equation in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ for example (previous homework exercise based of solving an equation in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ but when I came across this proof, I got stuck. I don't even know how to begin the proof since this isn't about solving equations. It's one of those exercises that are one of the last ones before the end of a section and I even asked my friend if he knew where to start but after $30$ minutes, we had no success.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931921/let-g-a-finite-group-of-order-m-with-identity-element-e-show-that-gm-e) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all of the action in the numerator happens modulo $m$. The key point here is that although the roots of unity look like they're multiplicative objects, because multiplication of things of the same base **adds** in the exponent, the underlying structure comes from additive arithmetic.

In this case, if $\zeta^k=\eta$ and $j\equiv k^{-1}\mod m$ then $\eta^{j}=\zeta^{qm+1}=\zeta$ by definition of an inverse modulo $m$. Similarly, if $\eta^j=\zeta$ then $\zeta^{kj}=\zeta$ and by definition $m$ is the smallest positive integer for which $\zeta^m=1$, so $\zeta^{kj-1}=1$ and therefore $m|(kj-1)$ and $j$ is the required inverse.

Comment: Ahh okay. I actually read a couple pages in my textbook and it talked about the modular inverses as well as the Euclidean Algorithm, which I believed you used here.

Comment: @i8Σπ_821 I use the division algorithm and definitions mostly, though I and the Euclidean algorithm is implicit in the fact that since $m$ is the smallest positive number for which $\zeta^m=1$ if $n>0$ such that $\zeta^n=1$ then $m|n$ since their gcd would be a smaller value otherwise.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Okay this should be enough to get me started.